# Is there a Regex to match all unicode Emojis?

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I need a Regex to match all unicode emojis.
I need this to check if a discord message has a Unicode Emoji in it.

```
// Here is a example of matching one Unicode Emoji
message.content.match(//g)
// or two
message.content.match(/|/g)
// and three
message.content.match(/||/g)
// then so on.
```

I have gotten up to like the last 300 or so emojis with this method then it stops working, sending all kinds of errors and stuff.

Is there a better way to do this? and if there is then can you give me an example in the comments. Im new to coding and don't really understand regex and some other stuff so having an example would help a lot. Also I code in JavaScript with node.js on Visual Studio Code.

UPDATE: there is a way that does work and i'm so grateful to Lioness100 for telling about it. There is a npm package called Emoji-Regex. Very useful!

Comment: If your browser supports it, `var emojiRegex = /\p{Emoji}/gu`.

Comment: I believe you're looking for [`emoji-regex`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/emoji-regex)

Comment: I could not get `\p{Emoji}` to work but `\p{Emoji_Presentation}` did.  See [this example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Unicode_Property_Escapes).

Answer (score 13):

Regex to match all emojis:

```
/(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/g
```

You can test it here: https://www.regextester.com/106421

Comment: Be careful with that first range. It matches punctuation marks like ‛ and “, currencies, mathematical operators, Coptic letters ... See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode_block#List_of_blocks. This is *way* more than just emojis. Arguably, the only "emoji-like" symbols in that range are geometric shapes, misc symbols and dingbats, which is only `[\u25a0-\u27bf]`, not `[\u2000-\u3300]`.

Answer (score 3):

For anyone interested, I spent some time and collected complete regular expression based off of [emoji standard](http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr51/):

https://gist.github.com/Saluev/604c9c3a3d6032770e15a0da143f73bd

For parsing single emoji, use either

```
re.match(EMOJI_SEQUENCE, string)
# or
EMOJI_REGEXP.match(string)
```

To match multiple emojis or custom patterns, insert `EMOJI_SEQUENCE` into pattern:

```
re.match(rf"{EMOJI_SEQUENCE}+\s*...", string)
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, and essentially it's a bigger version of what you have, sequenced longest to shortest.
*Note: Emoji-Regex doesn't always match correctly with skin-tone or compound emojis such as ‍ or ‍♀️, etc.*

The pattern:

```
/(?:‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍||||‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍❤️‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍‍|‍‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍❤️‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|‍‍|️‍️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍♀️|‍️|️‍♂️|️‍♀️|️‍♂️|️‍♀️|️‍♂️|️‍♀️|️‍|️‍⚧️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♂️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|⛹‍♀️|‍|‍|❤️‍|❤️‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍⚕️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍⚖️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍✈️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|⛹️‍♂️|⛹️‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍♂️|‍♀️|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍|‍❄️|‍☠️|‍⬛|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||#️⃣|0️⃣|1️⃣|2️⃣|3️⃣|4️⃣|5️⃣|6️⃣|7️⃣|8️⃣|9️⃣|✋|✋|✋|✋|✋|✌|✌|✌|✌|✌|☝|☝|☝|☝|☝|✊|✊|✊|✊|✊|✍|✍|✍|✍|✍|⛹|⛹|⛹|⛹|⛹||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||☺|☹|☠|❣|❤|✋|✌|☝|✊|✍|⛷|⛹|☘|☕|⛰|⛪|⛩|⛲|⛺|♨|⛽|⚓|⛵|⛴|✈|⌛|⏳|⌚|⏰|⏱|⏲|☀|⭐|☁|⛅|⛈|☂|☔|⛱|⚡|❄|☃|⛄|☄|✨|⚽|⚾|⛳|⛸|♠|♥|♦|♣|♟|⛑|☎|⌨|✉|✏|✒|✂|⛏|⚒|⚔|⚙|⚖|⛓|⚗|⚰|⚱|♿|⚠|⛔|☢|☣|⬆|↗|➡|↘|⬇|↙|⬅|↖|↕|↔|↩|↪|⤴|⤵|⚛|✡|☸|☯|✝|☦|☪|☮|♈|♉|♊|♋|♌|♍|♎|♏|♐|♑|♒|♓|⛎|▶|⏩|⏭|⏯|◀|⏪|⏮|⏫|⏬|⏸|⏹|⏺|⏏|♀|♂|⚧|✖|➕|➖|➗|♾|‼|⁉|❓|❔|❕|❗|〰|⚕|♻|⚜|⭕|✅|☑|✔|❌|❎|➰|➿|〽|✳|✴|❇|©|®|™|ℹ|Ⓜ|㊗|㊙|⚫|⚪|⬛|⬜|◼|◻|◾|◽|▪|▫)/
```

[regex101 demo](https://regex101.com/r/2ia4m2/7)

see https://github.com/sweaver2112/Regex-combined-emojis for more info

Answer (score 0):

```
message.content.match(/(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])/g);
```

[source](https://www.regextester.com/106421)

Comment: doest work for me